# Normalized mutual information(NMI) in Python?

Tags: python, networking, nmi

I get the concept of NMI, I just don't understand how it is implemented in Python. How i can using algorithms with networks.

```
For example:

Network   |    Karate club  |football
--------------------------------------
Louvain   |     0.7685      | 0.3424
--------------------------------------
LPA       |     0.4563      |0.9765    so on  

may you write a piece of code for this table, please?
```